# Laravel: parse this json data in view blade?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

Can someone help me, im trying to pass value to my view but im always getting an *Undefined variable: result *

Currently this is my view

```
@foreach($result as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->lastname }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->account_type}}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->college }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->address }}</td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
```

this is in my controller

```
$response = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid request'];

        try {

            if (strlen($data['output']) > 0) {

                $data = $data['output'];
                $result = DB::table('user_details')
                ->select('firstname', 'lastname', 'account_type', 'gender', 'college', 'address')
                ->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $data . '%')
                ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%' . $data . '%')
                ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $data . '%')
                ->get();              

                if ($result) {
                    $response = $result;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        }

       return view('search')->with('result', json_decode($response, true));
```

I want to display something like

```
First Name : juan
Last Name : dela cruz
Account Type : student
Gender : male
College : CON
Address : doon doon lang
```

Comment: You need to return a view, not `$response`, and pass `$response` to that view.

Comment: How about `return view('search')->with('result', $response)` ?

Comment: still getting
Undefined variable: result (View: /var/www/app/http/Features/Test/Views/partials/results.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
return view('search')->with('result', json_decode($response, true));
```

To:

```
$data['result'] = $response; // if $result is right. 
// send another variable
return view('search')->with($data);
```